# Free storage for documents in Microsoft OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

Google stores Google documents for free (they do not consume storage space on Google Drive).

Does OneDrive has a similar policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear that Microsoft has a policy like that. I just tested it by uploading a Word document to my OneDrive account, and my used storage amount went up.